# Meaning of $f(x\pm 0)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, functions, continuity

Let $f: (a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on the open interval $(a,b)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. I have seen the following expressions in a few different places (books, papers, etc.), but I cannot reconcile their meaning: $$f(x - 0)\qquad \text{and}\qquad f(x+0).$$
For example, this notation appears in the second paragraph of the following paper: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183493290. My guess is that
$$f(x-0) := \lim_{y\rightarrow x^-} f(y),$$ and similarly for $f(x+0)$ (when those limits exist). But I really do not know. Would be helpful for someone to clarify their meanings for me!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the meaning.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you!

Comment: @Satana FYI, according to Wikipedia's [One-sided limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) article, "In probability theory it is common to use the short notation: $f(x-)$ for the left limit and $f(x+)$ for the right limit."

Comment: You're absolutely right about this meaning. It is just a notation for one-sided limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments by [Kavi Rama Murthy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/142385/kavi-rama-murthy) and [Daniel Sehn Colao](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/649328/daniel-sehn-colao), your guess that $f(x-0) := \lim_{y \to x^{-}} f(y)$ and $f(x+0) := \lim_{y \to x^{+}} f(y)$ is correct.

Regarding other similar types of notation, I commented that Wikipedia's [One-sided limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) article states:

> In [probability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) it is common to use the short notation:
>   $f(x−)$ for the left limit and $f(x+)$ for the right limit.